# json format each object in a line

Tags: json, shell, jsonlines

```
cat 2.txt | ./jq '{(.id): .custom}'
```

above command outputs

```
{
  "1": {
    "results": "Success"
  }
}
{
  "2": {

    "input method": "touch",
    "from": "Prescription Center",

  }
}
{
  "3": {

    "entry point": "|All"
  }

}
```

Expected output :

I want to print/save each object in a line.

```
cat 2.txt | ./jq '{(.id): .custom}'

{ "1": {  "results": "Success" }  }
{ "2": {  "input method": "touch",  "from": "Prescription Center"  }  }
{ "3": {  "entry point": "|All" } }
```

will it be possible in shell script?

Comment: [Have you tried `cat 2.txt | ./jq -c '{(.id): .custom}'`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

Comment: -c option works , Thank you. you can post it in answer i will accept. jq is c program to parse json

Comment: My Ubuntu doesn't know any `jq`, and why do you have it in your local directory?  I'd be interested in that tool.

Comment: @Alfe, `sudo apt-get install jq`

Comment: Funny.  `apt-file` didn't show that, but `apt-get` could install it.  I guess I have to learn more about those two package management tools.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, an `apt-file update` did the trick; now the `apt-file list` also displays the `jq` package.  Seems to have appeared in the last months/years (before my last `apt-file update`).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per the [jq manual](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

> - `--compact-output` / `-c`:
>
>   By default, jq pretty-prints JSON output. Using this option will result in more compact output by instead putting each JSON object on a single line.

Therefore the following should work:

```
cat 2.txt | ./jq -c '{(.id): .custom}'
```

Comment: `jq` is so lovely.