# Splitting large JSON data using Unix command Split

Tags: json, bash, dataset

Issue with `Unix Split command` for **splitting large data**: `split -l 1000 file.json myfile`. Want to split this file into multiple files of 1000 records each. But Im getting the output as single file - no change.

**P.S.** File is created converting Pandas Dataframe to JSON.

**Edit:** It turn outs that my JSON is formatted in a way that it contains only one row. `wc -l file.json` is returning `0`

Here is the sample: `file.json`

```
[
{"id":683156,"overall_rating":5.0,"hotel_id":220216,"hotel_name":"Beacon Hill Hotel","title":"\u201cgreat hotel, great location\u201d","text":"The rooms here are not palatial","author_id":"C0F"},
{"id":692745,"overall_rating":5.0,"hotel_id":113317,"hotel_name":"Casablanca Hotel Times Square","title":"\u201cabsolutely delightful\u201d","text":"I travelled from Spain...","author_id":"8C1"}
]
```

Comment: Please clarify the requirements, e.g. by showing what each partition would look like. See [mcve] for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend spliting the JSON array with `jq` ([see manual](https://hyperpolyglot.org/json)).

```
cat file.json | jq length              # get length of an array
cat file.json | jq -c '.[0:999]'       # first 1000 items
cat file.json | jq -c '.[1000:1999]'   # second 1000 items
...
```

Notice `-c` for compact result (not pretty printed).

For automation, you can code a simple bash script to split your file into chunks given the array length (`jq length`).

Comment: Is their any possibility to add (,) comma after each line?

Answer (score 4):

Invoking jq once per partition plus once to determine the number of partitions would be extremely inefficient.  The following solution suffices to achieve the partitioning deemed acceptable in your answer:

```
jq -c ".[]" file.json | split -l 1000
```

If, however, it is deemed necessary for each file to be pretty-printed, you could run `jq -s .` for each file, which would still be more efficient than running `.[N:N+S]` multiple times.

If each partition should itself be a single JSON array, then see [Splitting / chunking JSON files with JQ in Bash or Fish shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881458/splitting-chunking-json-files-with-jq-in-bash-or-fish-shell)

Comment: This doesn't works. Have a look of the data here: https://gist.github.com/tahirsohaib/8b456aec7ebe44dcb212a4c30d378e4b

Comment: `jq -c .[]` results to: `zsh: no matches found: .[]`

Comment: @sohaib try `jq -c ".[]" file.json | split -l 1000`

Answer (score 1):

After asking elsewhere, the file was, in fact a single line.

[Reformatting with JQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25468990/6216) (in compact form), would enable the split, though to process the file would at least need the first and last character to be deleted (or add '[' & ']' to the split files)

Comment: I tried using jq but the problem isn't resolved. I ran this: cat merged.json | jq > newfile.json. It created new line for every object. Like 'id' is one line, 'overall_rating' is next line. So the data is still not usable with Unix Split command.